# jQuery pseudo classes

Tags: jquery

Is this correct?

```
var deleteIndex = 3;
$("ol li:nth-child(deleteIndex)").remove();
```

For some reason, this doesn't seem to work. Executing this clears the whole list.

Comment: If this is not allowed, is ther

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding the literal text 'deleteIndex'  into the jQuery selector rather than the number contained in the variable. Try this instead:

```
var deleteIndex = 3;
$("ol li:nth-child(" + deleteIndex + ")").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be if you try this:
`var deleteIndex = 3;
$("ol li:eq(deleteIndex)").remove();`

Comment: a'r has the correct answer.  It's the literal text versus variable issue.

Comment: you need to make `deleteIndex` not part of the string as a literal but as a variable using string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
var deleteIndex = 3;
$("ol li:nth-child(" + deleteIndex + ")").remove();
```

so that deleteIndex is converted to 3.  Or if 3 is a constant used only here, you could just use 3.

[It really works.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd28Y/)